# PMD Overridable method called during object construction

Tags: java, pmd

I have the following structure

```
public class parent {
    int value ; 
}

public class child extends parent {
    int childValue;
    public child(){}
    public child (int value){
          this.childValue = value ; // this line cause ConstructorCallsOverridableMethod warning during object construction
    }
}
```

Could you please advice how to solve this error ?

Comment: Is that the message that `pmd` gives you? Is it considered a warning?

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling a `setChildValue()` from the ctor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The PMD [rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/design.html#ConstructorCallsOverridableMethod) says:

> Calling overridable methods during construction poses a risk of invoking methods on an incompletely constructed object and can be difficult to debug. It may leave the sub-class unable to construct its superclass or forced to replicate the construction process completely within itself, losing the ability to call `super()`. If the default constructor contains a call to an overridable method, the subclass may be completely uninstantiable. Note that this includes method calls throughout the control flow graph - i.e., if a constructor `Foo()` calls a private method `bar()` that calls a public method `buz()`, this denotes a problem.

Example:

```
public class SeniorClass {
  public SeniorClass(){
      toString(); //may throw NullPointerException if overridden
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "IAmSeniorClass";
  }
}
public class JuniorClass extends SeniorClass {
  private String name;
  public JuniorClass(){
    super(); //Automatic call leads to NullPointerException
    name = "JuniorClass";
  }
  public String toString(){
    return name.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

#### Solution

Delete any call to overridable methods in the constructor or add the `final` modifier to that methods.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could follow follow Java's Naming Conventions and also make the `Child` class `final`

```
public final class Child extends Parent {
```

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely 2 ways to fix this issue.

1. Can you indeed make the method that are called in the constructor as `final`, but it comes with the drawback that subclasses would not be able to override the final method.
2. To create a private method used in constructor and overridable method, see snippet bellow.

---

```
public class Parent {
  
  private int counter;
  public Parent() {
    // setCounter(0); // this line raise the PMD warning
    updateCounter(0);
  }
  private void updateCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  public void setCounter(int counter) {
    updateCounter(counter);
  }

}

public class Child extends Parent {
  
  public void setCounter(int counter) {
    super.setCounter(counter);
    // do other stuff

  }
  
}
```